# Scrapy error: Spider not Found

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have already seen a similar question and tried the answer given but to no avail. Can someone please help me rectify this?

Thanks

```
hepz@ubuntu:~/Documents/project/project$ scrapy crawl NewsSpider.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module> 
execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 58, in run
spider = crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 44, in create
raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name)
KeyError: 'Spider not found: NewsSpider.py'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the [spider name](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.name), not the script name.

For example, if you have the following spider:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    ...
```

In this case, you would run it as:

```
scrapy crawl myspider
```